# fade element on scroll dow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to do the fade in the other side : `fadeIn` from down to up and not like now, `fadeOut` down to up

```js
var $elem = $('.test.fade');
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    $elem.clone().appendTo('body');
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.fade').each(function() {
        var bounds = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
           op = Math.max((bounds.height + Math.min(bounds.top, 0)) / bounds.height, 0);
        $(this).css('opacity', op);
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.test {
    height: 70vh;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test fade"></div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ye7rzbw/1/)

Thank you for help.

Comment: So, am I interpreting this correctly, you want the elements to fade in as you scroll down?

Comment: Yes but l want to keep getBoundingClientRect(); to calculate the position of the element relative to the viewport in order to calculate how much % of it is outside the viewport.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `op = 1 - (bounds.top / window.innerHeight);`?

Comment: Yeah something like this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the opacity calculation to this:

```
op = Math.max((bounds.height - Math.max(bounds.top, 0)) / bounds.height, 0);
```

So it becomes dependent on the bottom border of the boxes.

Comment: Thaank you!! :)